# How much vertical velocity do I have to apply to an object, which has set horizontal velocity, for it to start from point B and land on point A?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, velocity

How much vertical velocity do I have to apply to an object, which has set horizontal velocity, for it to start from point B and land on point A, even if point A and point B are on different heights?

Comment: Just as in the case of the range equation, there should generally be two answers that will satisfy the conditions of your question (e.g., two different launch angles that add to 90 degrees).  Do you have a constraint in mind that would limit your answer to only one vertical velocity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be simplified a little (if necessary) by relocating your coordinate frame so point B is at the origin (0,0) and assuming that point A is in the positive x direction. In this case, the original horizontal velocity also has to be positive.

This reduces your problem to the question:

*"For a frictionless projectile initially at position $(0,0)$ at $t=0$ and with horizontal velocity $u$, what vertical velocity $v$ is required so the projectile passes through the point $(X,Y)$"*

Notice first, that horizontal velocity is constant (as the acceleration due to gravity is in the vertical direction). So you can calculate the time when the particle will be at horizontal position $X$.

$T=X/u$

Elementary kinematics tells you that the vertical position $h$ of a particle moving at vertical velocity $v$ (starting from $h=0$ at $t=0$ follows the equation

$h = vt - gt^2/2$.

So substitute in $Y$ for $h$ and $X/u$ for $t$ and solve for $v$ as in

$Y = vX/u - g(X/u)^2/2$

with the final result that the required vertical velocity $v$ is given by

$v = Yu/x + gX/(2u)$

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object of mass $m$, starting at $A=(x_0,y_0)$ and travelling to $B=(x_1,y_1)$, with an initial velocity of $v=(v_x,v_y)$, then you can use the SUVAT equations to calculate the required value of velocity.

If no air resistance is present then velocity in the $x$ direction ($v_x$) remains constant. So $v_x=\text{distance travelled/time travelled}= (x_1-x_0)/t$. From this you can obtain the time the object has travelled for: $t=(x_1-x_0)/v_x$. Now in the $y$-direction, im going to again assume no air resistance, so the force acting on the object if $-mg$, acting in the $-y$ (downwards) direction, $F=ma$ (Newtons 2nd law), so $a=-g$. using the suvat equation $S=ut+\frac12at^2$, where s is the vertical displacement, equal to $y_1-y_0$ a is acceleration and $u$ is initial vertical velocity $v_y$ you can rearrange for $u$, $u=S/t-\frac12at$ or $v_y=((y_1-y_0)/t)-0.5(-g)t$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be at a height $h$ above the level of $B$. Then if we assume that when the particle reaches the point $A$ it is travelling horizontally, then by conservation of energy,
$$\frac12m(v_x^2+v_y^2)=mgh+\frac12mv_x^2$$
$$\implies v_y=\sqrt{2gh}$$

This is the same velocity that would be required to project the particle to a height $h$ immediately above it (i.e. if it were not moving horizontally).